# Alternative to if statement in this simple example

Tags: java, syntax, if-statement, return-value, return

```
if(metres >= 0) return true;
else return false;
```

Can I do this with a single calculation? (ignoring the ternary operator)

Comment: I wonder, which answer from the list below will you choose :)

Comment: +1 because no one ever bothers upvoting the question

Comment: +1 for the question that brought me couple easy points :)

Comment: You should write your own `isTrue` function, as this is [a](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Happy_%28Belated%29_Jed_Day!.aspx) [best](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/IsTrue%28%29.aspx) [practice](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/wtflibphp.aspx).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
return (metres >= 0);
```

Comment: :) Thank you, Michael Borgwardt! :)

Answer (score 6):

```
return metres >= 0;
```

Comment: +1. Because only you got rid of those useless parenthesis. Others might got this habit from programming Lisp, but I doubt it.

Comment: Not only Lisp. Pascal/Delphi programmers have to use parenthesis if some condition is more complicated. Code like: `if a > 0 and b > 0 then ...` does not compile :(